# Size of bit cell in flash memory

Tags: semiconductor-physics

If we consider a normal sd card, whose dimensions are 11x15x1 $mm^3$, there are 512,000,000,000 bits stored in 64 GB memory card.
If one bit is stored per cell, size of a cell would be 10e-14 m on each dimension, which is much smaller than dimensions of atom. The problem is not solved if we consider several bits stored per cell, because, it would need 10,000 bits per cell to bring a cell size comparable to size of an atom.
How then is memory stored in Flash memory?

Comment: I think you missed the fact that the radius of a sphere is proportional to the third root of it's volume, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eksceqm92ih and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+of+hydrogen+atom+in+meters. The difference actually is quite impressive.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we only have a single layer, not because this is *necessarily* the case, but because generally 3D electronic components are harder to design and construct than 2D. So we have an area of $11\ \mathrm{mm} \times 15\ \mathrm{mm} = 165\ \mathrm{mm^2}$. There are as you say $5\times10^{11}$ bits to store. This gives us $165\ \mathrm{mm^2} / 5\times10^{11} = 3\times10^{-10}\ \mathrm{mm^2}$ per bit. But a square with area $3\times10^{-10}\ \mathrm{mm^2}$ has side length of about $2\times10^{-5}\ \mathrm{mm} = 20\ \mathrm{nm}$ (take the square root). This is right around the [scale of the typical circuit fabrication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_nanometer).

The discrete nature of matter will indeed be a limit in the near future, but we haven't quite gotten our everyday devices to that point yet.